# Sort a 2-D Matrix Column and Row wise together

Tags: java, sorting, matrix

```
-1 -3 -2        -3 -2 -1
 2  3 -2        -2  2  3 
 5  7  4         4  5  7 
(Orignal)        (Sorted)
```

I can sort the matrix based on row only OR column only.
But I am unable to get the optimal solution for sorting the matrix considering the column as well as the row.

Any suggestions how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You can transform any 2D array into 1D array, and those are easy to sort.

You don't have to actually change the 2D array, just play with the indexes:

```
[0][0] = [0]
[1][0] = [length]
[N][K] = [(length*N) + K]
```

Comment: @UrviG - In 2D array index [0][0] is equivalent to index [0] in an 1D array. The index [1][0] is equivalent to [length of the row], and the general [N][K] index is equivalent to [(length of the row * N) + K].

Now that you have a 1D array, it's easy to sort it.

Comment: Thank you, I was aware of that .. But if I sort these 3 individual 1D arrays, the matrix would get sorted `row` wise only .

Comment: No, you do not look at 3 1D arrays. You look at 1 1D array with 9 elements in it.

Comment: `-1  -3  -2   2  3  -2   5  7  4`    Orignal matrix Array
`-3  -2  -2  -1  2   3   4  5  7`      Orignal Sorted Array 
How to get the solution from this? :/

Comment: Take element in [i] and put it in [i/3][i%3].

Comment: `element in [0] ie -3 will go at 00 -- true`


`element in [3] ie -1 will go at 10 -- in the answer matrix, -1 is at 03`

Comment: No, element [3], ie -1, will go to [3/3=1][3%3=0]. There is no such thing [0][3] (index out of bounds!).

Comment: ya sorry *02
so this element should go to 02. But acc to you it is going in 10

Answer (score 0):

Using these two functions:

```
public static void sortRows(int[][] matrix){
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        Arrays.sort(matrix[i]);
    }
}

public static void transpose(int[][] matrix){
    for (int i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < matrix[0].length; j++) {
            int tmp1 = matrix[i][j];
            int tmp2 = matrix[j][i];
            matrix[j][i] = tmp1;
            matrix[i][j] = tmp2;
        }
    }
}
```

you can sort the rows, transpose the matrix, sort the rows again (transposed columns) and transpose it back:

```
int[][] matrix = {{-1, -3, -2}, {2,  3, -2}, {5, 7,  -4}};
sortRows(matrix);
transpose(matrix);
sortRows(matrix);
transpose(matrix);
```